# Help translating calligraphy

Tags: translation, calligraphy, transcription

I own this painting with Chinese calligraphy I would Very grateful for help with a translation.

Thank you in advance. Dre[image]

Answer (score 3):

the calligraphy is "福如东海" in Chinese.

In English, it means "May your happiness be as vast as the East Sea". It's often used to wish someone immense good fortune or blessings.

福: Fortune, luck, happiness, blessings

如: As, like

东海: The East Sea (referring to the East China Sea)

As requested, the words on the right hand side is "吾兒俊林留念".

吾兒: For my son

俊林: Jun Lin, his/her son's name

留念: as a souvenir

Comment: You might want to translate the texts on the right too.

Comment: added as requested.